# Move animation won't work with div jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

Javascript/jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#box").animate({ 
            top: "+=50px",
            }, 2000 );

    }
```

CSS

```
    #box{

        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
        width:300px;
        height:250px;
        background:#D8D8D8;
        border:2px solid black;
        position: relative;

    }
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Also, if anyone knows how it's possible to change the div's size and rotate it while it's moving  could you tell me. I would like it so that all the 3 animations are happening at the same time. Is this possible and if so, how?
Thanks a lot for any answers in advance.

Comment: you are implicitly setting the value of `top` to `"+=50px"`. If you see the CSS properties in your browser's developer tools, you'll see a property error. Best idea would be to fetch the current value of `top` using the `.css()` function and then add 50 to it, then set top to the new value.

Comment: How exactly is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your document ready function syntax
Your syntax should be like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     /*your code*/
 });
```

I have added fiddle with your working code.
http://jsfiddle.net/tRYuX/

Comment: Such a simple mistake causes so much hassle and time. Thanks a million for the answer !!